# JavaScript: Index object by array?

Tags: javascript

I'm storing some collision squares with properties in my JavaScript code. The easiest way seems to be an object using arrays as the index. My code should look something like this:

```
// left, top, width, height
const array = [0, 0, 8, 16];
var rectangles = {};
rectangles[array] = {foo: bar};
```

Wanted to make sure this is a valid and sound method. I remember people saying objects in JS are always indexed by string, this might not convert accordingly then. It thus seems safer to use a string (`const s = array[0] + " " + array[1] + " " + array[2] + " " + array[3]`) but I was hoping that doing it this way might allow me to extract entries by specifying their array so I wouldn't need my own string separator function to match the values.

```
// Obviously I'd use a more complex function to get the values I need
const this_rectangle = rectangles[[0, 0, 8, 16]];
```

Comment: is each array that you want to use as a key unique?

Comment: I'd say you're better of by fully acknowledging that your index must be a string, and as such include some helper function that derives that string from a given array. Whether that function actually simply concatenates the array values, or does something more elaborate is then changeable whenever you need it to.

Comment: `rectangles[array]` will convert `array` to a string. So the key for your object will be `'0,0,8,16'`.

Comment: Sounds like I should go with a string then, perhaps use `rectangle.toString()` when setting the object index to convert the array internally for safe measure. Thanks.

Comment: Can you clear up, whether the array containing the coordinates itself (it's object identity) or it's values provide identity? That's quite important with regards to what solutions are feasible (`Map`, `WeakMap`, ...).

Answer (score 1):

How about you use a WeakMap :D

```js
// left, top, width, height
const array = [0, 0, 8, 16];
var rectangles=new WeakMap(); //declaration
rectangles.set(array,{foo:"bar"}); //setting

//example
console.log( rectangles.get(array) ); //getting
```

Comment: Good idea, will keep in mind thanks!

Comment: This relies on the object identity of the array, which might be a problem.

Comment: indeed it does but they themselves talked about using arrays themselves as the index and not their values

Comment: You're right, it's still a bit unclear whether the array itself provides identity or it's values. Maybe they'll clear that up. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Objects are indeed indexed by string exclusively. Found a convenient solution with this in mind:

```
const array = [0, 0, 8, 16].toString();
rectangles[array] = {foo: "bar"};
```

And to extract the positions back into an array when iterating through rectangles:

```
for(let pos in rectangle) {
    const data = rectangle[pos];
    const poses = pos.split(",");
}
```

Comment: what happens if 2 arrays have the same string value?